# Need help solving for a linear system $x_1$ + $2x_2$ = $λx_1$ & $2x_1$ + $2x_2$ = $λx_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on an exercise problem that is as follows. Find all real values of λ for which the system has a non trivial solution

$x_1$ + $2x_2$ = $λx_1$

$2x_1$ + $x_2$ = $λx_2$

I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I rewrote the equation as:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2\\
        2 & 1\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

multiplied by

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

which equals

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        λx_1\\
        λx_2\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I then multiplied the both sides by the inverse of the the 2x2 matrix giving me just 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

on the left hand side and I solved for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $λx_1$ and $λx_2$. After this I plugged the values I got for $x_1$ and $x_2$ back into the first equation in the linear system. I feel like I'm on the wrong track, so any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I corrected it. I wrote down the intial linear system wrong.

Comment: Move everything to one side of the equal sign, correct like terms, turn it into a matrix. Solve for when the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know linear algebra, then rewrite the first equation to $x_2=\frac{x_1(\lambda-1)}{2}$ and substitute this into the second equation. Then we obtain
$$
(\lambda+1)(\lambda-3)x_1=0.
$$
Now argue that we have a non-trivial solution only for $(\lambda+1)(\lambda-3)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\lambda \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix},$$
so $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$. Can you find all eigenvalues of that matrix using, for example, characteristic polynomial?

Comment: I don't know what an eigenvalue is. Looking ahead in the textbook, it's a topic in the next section, so I'm assuming the textbook wants me to solve it without knowing what an eigenvalue is.

Comment: @PCR what if your textbook wants to lure you to the idea of eigenvctors and eigenvalues? In my time, I had much, much more trouble with those teachers who did not want me to look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

**The mistake you made:** You have chosen $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$. So you have $Ax=\lambda x$ in the matrix equation form. When you multiply $A^{-1}$, you will get $x=Ix=A^{-1}Ax=\lambda A^{-1}x$. Observe the right hand side involves another matrix $A^{-1}$. Hence you are not getting the solution. Consider the technique suggested by 'Dietrich Burde' and try to generalize. Your text book is probably designed in such a way that you can understand the generalizations in the next sections.